# Form on Sharepoint Library to be completed by different users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pdf

I have developed an editable pdf form for my client.  The user fills in an PDF form and then the form gets uploaded to SharePoint to start a workflow.

In the next step of the workflow, a task is assigned to another user that needs to add information to the submitted pdf form. The user needs to open the editable pdf form, complete the fields and submit. Then the workflow needs to continue.

But when the user receives the task with that form, the only option is for the user to download the editable pdf form and complete it, but then how do they 'overwrite' the current form in the library?  Or is there a way that the user can open the editable pdf form straight from SharePoint to complete the required fields?

Maybe someone has an out of the box alternative for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you scenario, maybe you can first make the workflow just end here. Create another library which receives the submitted pdf, and add a new workflow here when triggered a new file is uploaded and then finish the rest process.

Comment: That might work, thank you.  Then one can delete the files in the previous libraries and we can keep better control on who should access which library and see which info.